# How to do Unicode escaping in YAML multiline string?

Tags: unicode, yaml

Is it possible to use Unicode character escaping (e.g. `\u2009`) in YAML multiline strings?

```
this_escape_works: "foo\u2009bar"
this_escape_doesnt: >
  foo\u2009bar
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per [the YAML1.2 spec](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2787109) double quoted style for scalars is:

> the only style capable of expressing arbitrary strings, by using “\” escape sequences. This comes at the cost of having to escape the “\” and “"” characters.

So folded scalars do not support escaping and you have to do

```
this_escape_works: "foo\u2009bar"
this_escape_doesnt: "foo\u2009bar\n"
```

Please note that contrary to @nj_'s claim the folding indicator `>` (it is not an operator) doesn't do "newlines become spaces" in general and certainly not for [the final line break](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2797119)